# How to remove a particular word at specific line number in a text file using cmd script without creating new file?

Tags: batch-file

i wanted to delete a specific word at a given line number in a text file, using cmd batch file. And i do not want to create a new output file, wanted to do the modifications in the input file.

For example i have a test.text file which contains below information:

hello
how are you>
can you tell me?
where is the restaurant
where it is nearby
can can you tell me again
it is nearby sir
where thanks

i wanted to delete "where" from line number 4,8 and first occurence of "can" from line number 6.
Can someone please help me??

Comment: You need to make an attempt at the code instead of asking others to do it for you. (This is not "code on demand").

Comment: AFAIK, you will need to output the changes to a temp file and rename the temp file to the original file. I have never seen any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This Batch file do *exactly what you requested*:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" test.txt ^& del test.txt') do (
   set "line=%%b"
   rem i wanted to delete "where" from line number 4
   if %%a equ 4 (
      set "line=!line:where =!"
   rem i wanted to delete "where" from line number 8
   ) else if %%a equ 8 (
      set "line=!line:where =!"
   rem and first occurence of "can" from line number 6.
   ) else if %%a equ 6 (
      set "line=!line:can can=can!"
   )
   echo !line! >> test.txt
)
```

Well, perhaps the only doubt is if in line 6 is *the first* or *the second* "can" word which is deleted...

Comment: well, you add a trailing space to each line. Besides that, this *exactly*  answers the question.